# What is a Ruby regex to match a function name?

Tags: ruby, regex

Our app uses the `send` method to call functions on our objects.
Unfortunately, some times the string passed to `send` may not be a legit method name in Ruby. Does anyone know of a regexp that would allow us to check this?

And by legit, I mean a method name that doesn't start with "?", etc. I don't care whether the object responds to the method, because we use `method_missing` in this case, and we actually want it to be used, which would only happen for methods for which the object doesn't respond.

Technically, I'm looking for a regexp which [does this](http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/ruby/syntax.html#ident) :

> Ruby identifiers are consist of
>   alphabets, decimal digits, and the
>   underscore character, and begin with a
>   alphabets(including underscore). There
>   are no restrictions on the lengths of
>   Ruby identifiers.

Comment: I thought there was a question in SO about a regex to match a variable name, which'd be somewhat relevant to this question, but I can't find it.

Comment: If you arrived here looking for a regex that you could use to roughly search for where a method is being used, you could use (ripgrep example): `rg '(^|[^_a-zA-Z0-9:])bunny([^_a-zA-Z0-9:]|$)'` <-- this is pretty liberal, but Ruby allows a lot of edge cases

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `Symbol#inspect` quotes the name when it is not a valid identifier. A valid symbol becomes `":hello!"` when inspected, but an invalid one becomes `":\"invalid!?\""`. This handles exotic symbols like `:foo=`, `:[]=`, and any other valid method name.

Adding the additional requirement that `@`-names are valid identifiers but not valid method names gives us this:

```
class Symbol
  def method_name?
    return /[@$"]/ !~ inspect
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow, very elegant :) I'd +1 you if I hadn't used up my votes today.

Comment: I like it! I'll +1 you as I haven't used up mine just yet :)

Comment: This is the best way to handle the situation. Rely on Ruby to use its  heuristics rather than try to recreate them on your own, then sense when there's a failure/mismatch. I think it should be part of Object instead of Symbol though, but Symbol will do.

Comment: You can make the above solution a bit shorter/nicer by replacing the line `return (not /[@"]/ =~ inspect)` with `/[@"]/ !~ inspect`

Comment: Don't forget about globals:  /[@$"]/ would be safer.

Answer (score 5):

What if it is a legit method name, but the method doesn't actually exist on the object you're attempting to send it to?

Either way, you should check that the object responds to a method before attempting to invoke it, no matter if the string is a legit method name of not. You can do this by using the `Object#respond_to?` method.

For example:

```
obj = Person.new
method = "set_name"

if obj.respond_to?(method)
  obj.send(method, "foo")
end
```

If you want to make sure a string is a legit method name you'd want to use regular expressions.. something like `/^([a-zA-Z_]+|\[\])[\?!=]?$/` should work for general methods. Regardless my point still stands for making sure this object responds to a method name

Comment: A legit method name is a method that is recognized by Ruby as a method name... for example `?echo` isn't a legit method name.

Comment: Right, am I'm saying you should be checking that the object responds to the method before invoking it. Did you try it before downvoting?

Comment: Hum. no, I don't want to check whether the object responds, because basically n our case, the object responds to _all_ methods. We use method_missing.

Comment: And, yes, I asked for a regex. I'm sorry you felt offended, but your response wasn't answering the question at all when you initially wrote it, and it still doesn't, because I'm looking for a regexp that matches all possible ruby method names. For example, it doesn't match `hello1` which is a legit method name.

Comment: Julien, you edited your message with the regex tag after I had posted. The whole point of using `method_missing` is so you don't have to check if the method name is a legit method name or not. I think you need to show more code so people can understand what you're trying to do. I assure you just having the regexp isn't much help if the rest of the logic is wrong

Comment: Sorry, look at the revision history, regex was here from the begining and even as a tag!

Answer (score 1):

Ruby method identifiers allowed in source code can be matched by this:

```
# Yes, upper-case first letters are legal
/\A(?:[a-z_]\w*[?!=]?|\[\]=?|<<|>>|\*\*|[!~+\*\/%&^|-]|[<>]=?|<=>|={2,3}|![=~]|=~)\z/i
```

However, note that methods may be defined that don't match this pattern:

```
class Foo
  define_method("!dumb~name"){ puts "yup" }
 end
 Foo.new.send('!dumb~name')
 #=> yup
```

**Edit**: Updated to add all the [Operator Expressions](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/frameset.html?content=http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html%23operatorexpressions).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure regexp is the way to go here but here's a try

```
def could_be_method_name?(m)
   match = /^([a-zA-Z_]([\w]*[\w!?=]$){0,1})/.match(m)
   return match == nil ? false : match[1].length==m.length
end
```

Ruby method names must start with a letter or an underscore. They can only contain alphanumeric characters but the last character is allowed to also be !, ?, or =.

Comment: this wont match "[]", "[]=", "<<", etc or uppercase method names (which are valid, just not conventional)

Comment: @JonaElfström Instead of testing the lengths, you should anchor your regex at the start and end of the input: `/\A...\z/`. (While it is unlikely that there would be a newline in this context, note that `^` is only start of line, not start of input.)